# jq construct with value strings spanning multiple lines

Tags: json, jq, string-literals

I am trying to form a JSON construct using `jq` that should ideally look like below:-

```
{
  "api_key": "XXXXXXXXXX-7AC9-D655F83B4825",
  "app_guid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "time_start": 1508677200,
  "time_end": 1508763600,
  "traffic": [
    "event"
  ],
  "traffic_including": [
    "unattributed_traffic"
  ],
  "time_zone": "Australia/NSW",
  "delivery_format": "csv",
  "columns_order": [
    "attribution_attribution_action",
    "attribution_campaign",
    "attribution_campaign_id",
    "attribution_creative",
    "attribution_date_adjusted",
    "attribution_date_utc",
    "attribution_matched_by",
    "attribution_matched_to",
    "attribution_network",
    "attribution_network_id",
    "attribution_seconds_since",
    "attribution_site_id",
    "attribution_site_id",
    "attribution_tier",
    "attribution_timestamp",
    "attribution_timestamp_adjusted",
    "attribution_tracker",
    "attribution_tracker_id",
    "attribution_tracker_name",
    "count",
    "custom_dimensions",
    "device_id_adid",
    "device_id_android_id",
    "device_id_custom",
    "device_id_idfa",
    "device_id_idfv",
    "device_id_kochava",
    "device_os",
    "device_type",
    "device_version",
    "dimension_count",
    "dimension_data",
    "dimension_sum",
    "event_name",
    "event_time_registered",
    "geo_city",
    "geo_country",
    "geo_lat",
    "geo_lon",
    "geo_region",
    "identity_link",
    "install_date_adjusted",
    "install_date_utc",
    "install_device_version",
    "install_devices_adid",
    "install_devices_android_id",
    "install_devices_custom",
    "install_devices_email_0",
    "install_devices_email_1",
    "install_devices_idfa",
    "install_devices_ids",
    "install_devices_ip",
    "install_devices_waid",
    "install_matched_by",
    "install_matched_on",
    "install_receipt_status",
    "install_san_original",
    "install_status",
    "request_ip",
    "request_ua",
    "timestamp_adjusted",
    "timestamp_utc"
  ]
}
```

What I have tried unsuccessfully thus far is below:-

```
json_construct=$(cat <<EOF
{
"api_key": "6AEC90B5-4169-59AF-7AC9-D655F83B4825",
"app_guid": "komacca-s-rewards-app-au-ios-production-cv8tx71",
"time_start": 1508677200,
"time_end": 1508763600,
"traffic": ["event"],
"traffic_including": ["unattributed_traffic"],
"time_zone": "Australia/NSW",
"delivery_format": "csv"
"columns_order": ["attribution_attribution_action","attribution_campaign","attribution_campaign_id","attribution_creative","attribution_date_adjusted","attribution_date_utc","attribution_matched_by","attribution_matched_to","attributio
network","attribution_network_id","attribution_seconds_since","attribution_site_id","attribution_tier","attribution_timestamp","attribution_timestamp_adjusted","attribution_tracker","attribution_tracker_id","attribution_tracker_name","
unt","custom_dimensions","device_id_adid","device_id_android_id","device_id_custom","device_id_idfa","device_id_idfv","device_id_kochava","device_os","device_type","device_version","dimension_count","dimension_data","dimension_sum","ev
t_name","event_time_registered","geo_city","geo_country","geo_lat","geo_lon","geo_region","identity_link","install_date_adjusted","install_date_utc","install_device_version","install_devices_adid","install_devices_android_id","install_
vices_custom","install_devices_email_0","install_devices_email_1","install_devices_idfa","install_devices_ids","install_devices_ip","install_devices_waid","install_matched_by","install_matched_on","install_receipt_status","install_san_
iginal","install_status","request_ip","request_ua","timestamp_adjusted","timestamp_utc"]
}
EOF)
```

followed by:-

```
echo "$json_construct" | jq '.'
```

I get the following error:-

> parse error: Expected separator between values at line 10, column 15

I am guessing it is because of the string literal which spans to multiple lines that `jq` is unable to parse it.

Comment: You don't need to use $(cat ... EOF).  Just set `json_construct='...'` directly with single quotes `'`.  here is a [**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##ZZFNT8QgEIbv/RWEmOzFrXXXfmjiYdV49OJBE2MIC9NdaguVjybrx2@vYK21cS4MPO8wL8OWmn3fV0ZJwpQ0VjtmLxfvEUKYtoK8wAFfIPz4G8t8c32@vMnS9LZYX50VqxQfD@KW7Jzgc3WIgVvRADGWausVp2lSZHm@SpKJgeQ/JM/W2Ug0LUvBPHjyW38AHUiLff78lxMhWe24kLtJ6SS1Vouts8DJeM9UGFq@KQnB78b5d9Na0JO7@4fBLodadKAPpFS6ocEzZqYbGFO1a6QhSnPQU8OxnfCjnOUsLN@lXhXH8ZgGD34iTUsor7wF4P@Js4Pp6HMRAdsrdDT/KvSBqlcU9/0X "Bash – Try It Online") example.

Comment: Am using `$(cat... EOF)` because I am the values shown here are actually variables. I understand you can pass arguments though.

Comment: Can you provide the variables?  It should be pretty easy to incorporate those.  e.g. `json_construct='{"api_key":'"$key"'"}'` - note careful use of `'`.

Comment: You have `jq`; use it to construct your JSON instead of `cat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input "JSON" is not valid JSON, as indicated by the error message.

The first error is that a comma is missing after the key/value pair: "delivery_format": "csv", but there are others -- notably, JSON strings cannot be split across lines.  Once you fix the key/value pair problem and the JSON strings that are split incorrectly, `jq .` will work with your text. (Note that once your input is corrected, the longest JSON string is quite short -- 50 characters or so -- whereas jq has no problems processing strings of length 10^8 quite speedily ...)

Generally, jq is rather permissive when it comes to JSON-like input, but if you're ever in doubt, it would make sense to use a validator such as the online validator at jsonlint.com

By the way, the jq FAQ does suggest various ways for handling input that isn't strictly JSON -- see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json

Answer (score 6):

Use `jq` itself:

```
my_formatted_json=$(jq -n '{
  "api_key": "XXXXXXXXXX-7AC9-D655F83B4825",
  "app_guid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "time_start": 1508677200,
  "time_end": 1508763600,
  "traffic": ["event"],
  "traffic_including": ["unattributed_traffic"],
  "time_zone": "Australia/NSW",
  "delivery_format": "csv",
  "columns_order": [
    "attribution_attribution_action",
    "attribution_campaign",
    ...,
    "timestamp_utc"
  ]
}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Along the lines of [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910083/8379597)'s suggestion since jq can read raw text data you could just use a jq filter to generate a legal json object from your script variables.  For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# whatever logic you have to obtain bash variables goes here
key=XXXXXXXXXX-7AC9-D655F83B4825
guid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

# now use jq filter to read raw text and construct legal json object
json_construct=$(jq -MRn '[inputs]|map(split(" ")|{(.[0]):.[1]})|add' <<EOF
api_key $key
app_guid $guid
EOF)

echo $json_construct
```

Sample Run (assumes executable script is in `script.sh`)

```bash
$ ./script.sh
{ "api_key": "XXXXXXXXXX-7AC9-D655F83B4825", "app_guid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU9NT4NAEL3vrxhbksKB1i@0mvbgV2@NiScTQsgAIyziLu4uYCP@dty9NPoOL/MyL/PeZKiraZqfrDIuVpkVjM1hqNBQTwoaWfIcDrKDCnsCI0FmBrkA54QeFcesIQ2ltFSRIvZOh@3rEeH13cNN@HgVRbv1xf3l@jxiZceLPw4HFynkAJ0mqD/hjTfGZtswRViAwgEMfRlAUUAuhTaqyw00VGIDtZbCdqopN8zN6dGw9Xx7K9y/CFjEXLSd0cn4ga2v24YbfwazYPz2l/FpEtwu47PkJxixKBaw2Tw97xi2PLWvgGfJijZ1tcFzzOw@YIzySoL3P3OafgE)